# Call function in jQuery from AJAX response

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm battling with a question for quite some time and I'm unable to find the answer. I'm using Script# with jQuery. In Script# I've defined the following functions:

```
(function($) {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Scrn

    window.Scrn = function Scrn() {
    }
    Scrn.openSuccess = function Scrn$openSuccess(txt) {
        /// <param name="txt" type="String">
        /// </param>
        $('#alrtS').css('display', 'block');
        $('#alrtS span').html(txt);
    }
    Scrn.openModal = function Scrn$openModal(cap, txt) {
        /// <param name="cap" type="String">
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="txt" type="String">
        /// </param>
        $('#frmModalLabel').html(cap);
        $('#frmModalBody').html(txt);
        $("#frmModal").modal("show");
    }


    Scrn.registerClass('Scrn');
})(jQuery);
```

From another script I make an AJAX request on which a piece of Javascript is returned.

```
(function($) {
    clsAJAX.fnAJAX = function clsAJAX$fnAJAX(hash) {
        var sdata = {};
        sdata.script = scrp;
        sdata.page = true;
        jqAO.data = sdata;
        jqAO.dataType = 'script';
        jqAO.cache = true;
        jqAO.url = url;
        jqAO.success = function(data, textStatus, request) {
        };
        $.ajax(jqAO);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

My question is, how can the response Javascript call the code inside the jQuery function? E.g: The server returns a Javascript code

```
Scrn.openSuccess("test");doucment.title="foo page";
```

Then I'll get an error that the function Scrn.openSuccess doesn't exist. So, what should the returned code be like to call Scrn.openSuccess()?

As for why there's a lot of odd variables like jqAO, Script# doesn't support direct input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it wasn't that complicated.
Returned Javascript code:

```
$(function(){ Scrn.openSuccess("test");doucment.title="foo page"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the ajax as a function which can be called from other scopes

```
(function ($) {
    //create a named function reference in the global scope so that script in another scopes can use it
    window.myAjax = function () {
        var sdata = {};
        sdata.script = scrp;
        sdata.page = true;
        jqAO.data = sdata;
        jqAO.dataType = 'script';
        jqAO.cache = true;
        jqAO.url = url;
        jqAO.success = function (data, textStatus, request) {};
        $.ajax(jqAO);
    }

    myAjax();
})(jQuery);
```

then in the other script just call

```
myAjax()
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited the OP, please give your input according to it.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the result, I changed the syntax of your code, more object oriented, you don't need to name the functions if they are object methods

```
(function($) {
   // Scrn
    window.Scrn = {
        openSuccess : function(txt) {
            /// <param name="txt" type="String">
            /// </param>
            $('#alrtS').css('display', 'block');
            $('#alrtS span').html(txt);
        },
        openModal : function(cap, txt) {
            /// <param name="cap" type="String">
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="txt" type="String">
            /// </param>
            $('#frmModalLabel').html(cap);
            $('#frmModalBody').html(txt);
            $("#frmModal").modal("show");
        }    
    }
    clsAJAXX = {
        fnAJAX : function(hash,successHandler,errorHandler) {
            // Data sent to server I guess
            var sdata = {};
            sdata.script = "";
            sdata.page = true;
            // Ajax request parameters
            var jqAO = {};
            jqAO.data = sdata;
            jqAO.dataType = 'script';
            jqAO.cache = true;
            jqAO.url = "http://dummy.com/getmyscript.jsp";
            jqAO.success = successHandler;
            jqAO.error = errorHandler;
            $.ajax(jqAO);
        }
    }
    //Call
    clsAJAXX.fnAJAX("myhash",Scrn.openSuccess,null);
})(jQuery);
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/AjYF2/
This demo shows the call of success handler in the AJAX function - It is just an example as I commented the Jquery Ajax call (need a proper url so) and replaced it by a call.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the OP, please give your input according to it.